# flash objects overlap when window is resized?

Tags: css, flash, actionscript-3, html

Here is the link

http://alvotechnologies.com/demo/fungi/

when resizing the window, swf objects overlaps??

Comment: Do you want to know how one should let multiple flash instances overlap each other? What is your question?

Comment: that site is only one swf object which exhibits overlapping layers when the window is resized.

Comment: overlapping layers.. Sorry i can not get you.. how can the layers be overlapped?? Actually i do not have fla but it was asked to me by my friend and

Comment: I am asking why the flash objects means movieclips/ displayObject overlap when the window containing the swf is resized?? I have got minus two for it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not dictated a minimum size for the window (or say, body element or a div element) so the browser does not know it needs to produce scrollbars at any particular resize point. Since the browser continues to shrink your SWF, the SWF repositions its elements at the smaller and smaller sizes until they overlap. This isn't strictly a flash problem, but a CSS problem.

Edit: You've also told the SWF Object to not scale the content, which when combined with no minimum size forces overlap.